# Copy/highlight text using applescript with Javascript

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, applescript

I am writing a applescript program and i need to copy a section of text.
Now i have my code for click, but instead of clicking i want it to copy, if i can not copy it can i highlight it?Thanks in advance for your help.

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('yt-uix-button-content')[9].click()" in document 1
```

Comment: You can always use innerHTML or innerText (without the HTML markup) and set it to variable